# How to secure a URL that has the userID

Tags: php, web-services, api, url, encryption

I am connecting to a web service to get the user information and then generating a Url with their id and send that URL over to the user to check if their info are up to date if not they can edit and submit. I want to hash or encrypt the userID from the URL am using PHP to make the calls. 
this is a URL example http://secure.gethope.net/F3/Basic-low-bar.php?id=123

Comment: Consider abstracting them rather than encoding them, E.g. `select real_user_id from link_table where some_long_random_string = what_you_emailed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use HTTPS on your entire website. It's free. This is no longer negotiable; you must have HTTPS to be secure.
2. [Do NOT encrypt/hash URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php). This leads you down the path of, "I'll write my own encryption," which will end up disastrous unless you happen to be a cryptography engineer and you're getting your design audited by at least one independent cryptography engineer.

   - Use a CSPRNG to generate a random token which you use in your SELECT query instead of the primary key.
3. This actually isn't a programming question.